# How to parse the data which contains Html tags like style, color,font family, fontsize and set in textview in android

Tags: android, html, textview, font-family

I have a textview and want to set the data parsing from the server. But I am getting problem to set the text in textview because text contains style=&amp , ;quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Georgia, Cambria, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;&quot;&amp
Is there any way to set the data in textview?
Data is given below

&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: Georgia, Cambria, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;&quot;&gt;Who among the following is known for his work on medicine during the Gupta period?&lt;/span&gt;

Comment: Either strip that stuff out before you pass it to `Html.fromHtml()`, or you will need to parse it yourself. I am not aware of a generic CSS-to-`Spanned` translator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i already do that but nothing happened after strip i passed my string to Html.from then it will convert to <span> </span> tag

Answer (score 0):

Use Jsoup to transform your text to Jsoup Document. From here you can extract all Html tag data easily. Example

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

//Extract html tag
Element tags = document.select("<tag>").first();
// Do your job
```